# Data transferring between services, repositories and model

Tags: php, design-patterns, laravel, domain-driven-design, dto

I'm having a hard time to decide the best practice to translate data between application layers in my case between the `UserService` which receive an update request that contains the following:

```
{
    "first_name" : "somename",
    "last_name" : "somename",
    "gender" : "male"
}
```

And the `UserRepository` which expect to receive the data as:

```
{
    "fname" : "somename",
    "lname" : "somename",
    "gender" : "male"
}
```

is `DTO's` a good approach in this scenario or there's another approach that might be suitable here?

Comment: How come they use different fields, wouldn't it have been easier to just mirror the database? Exposing database column names isn't really a security issue any more and is little more than security through obscurity.
One option would be to ensure the Service matches the Repository so the database doesn't need to be altered, the second would be to use an Adapter class that will transform data on the fly to a Repository compatible format.

Comment: @Everon i already matched the values on most cases, but i'm refactoring a legacy system which i don't have this flexibility in some cases, so for the Adapter approach can you please reference some articles, examples it would be much of a help, thanks

Comment: It's very simple, it's a class that can either be instantiated or use static methods that take input and modify the data and sending it back out again.

An example would be a class called `MyAdapter` that has one method `convert()` which accepts arrays (or any thing if needed), it performs the changes as needed - in this case changing `first_name` to `fname` and so on.

Another approach as you have mentioned is to use an object but this will add some extra complexity but would eliminate your problem.

A class like `Person` that can be sent to a repository and then getters used to store data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your domain should not know anything about your persistence. You will give your domain entity to your repository. Your repository should be responsible to translate this into something your database is familiar with.

Comment: no prob @AboElzooz . If you are interested I started a blog series on practical domain driven design. First post came out today. You can view it here http://sneakycode.net/intro-to-practical-domain-driven-design/